# Send a picture file in Post having only a remote URL to it

Tags: javascript, rest

I'm writing an angularJS application, but for the sake of the example let's pretend it's vanilla javascript.

I'm fetching a JSON object from a remote service,

[{'image': 'http://img.com/img1.jpg'},{'image': 'http://img.com/img2.jpg'}, ...]

Now, I'm fetching this with a get, and i'd like to post the image, as a file with a post.
Thing is I'd like to do this all client side, but I'm not sure how i can fetch an url and transform into a "file" that i can send in post.

Suggestions?

Comment: So, you want to "download" the image to your server files in the backend? What language are you POSTing to?

Comment: I'd like to download the image on the client end. I'm posting to nodejs.

Comment: On the client end, just put an image tag. That will download from the other site, just like it downloads images from your server.

Comment: Do i need to listen to the image to be loaded before sending the post ? (and in the post, how can i refer to the image? )